# Gubernatorial election 2017 in Jakarta - dates when Governor takes office

Tags: election, local-government

Does anyone knows when the next Governor of Jakarta will take office? I know elections are scheduled on Feb 15, 2017 but is there a fixed period for the Governor elect to actually take office following election? 
Links to sources would be greatly appreciated.